Aggregation Pipeline input from Readonly Analytical Nodes Output to Primary Node
I am intending on designing a MongoDB Atlas cluster with a typical three node replicaset that are all electable as primary. Then adding in a couple of readonly analytical nodes for offloading heavier query workloads.
I am wondering if I can configure an aggregation pipeline in a way that selectively queries the readonly analytical nodes for input then still outputs or merges the results into the regular primary electable replicaset nodes in order to isolate the query load to the readonly nodes.

Could you clarify what is your setup? I understand that you have 5 nodes in total: a primary node, two normal secondary nodes and two non-voting secondaries you call 'readonly analytical nodes`?

Read the documentation, Read Preference: "For aggregation pipeline operations that include the $out or $merge stages, the pipeline runs on the primary member regardless of read preference setting."

@WernfriedDomscheit I think it might not be 100% true, as according to $merge docs in newer versions of drivers read operations can be delegated to secondary nodes.

@hnwoh, you are right, I created a ticket for it.

I don't know if I understand your setup correctly, but I assume your replica set consists of:

1 primary node
2 standard secondary nodes
2 non-voting secondary nodes, which don't participate in the election process and can't become primary

Mechanism you are looking for is Read Preference. As you work with Atlas, I assume that you have Mongo >= 5.0, so read preference secondary/secondaryPreferred should be respected wrt read operations in your pipeline. Writes will always be performed on the primary node and you can't change this behavior.
There is a caveat though - make sure that MongoDB client/driver you use supports $merge and $out execution on secondaries. E.g. PyMongo supports that behavior since 4.1 version.
Also, you can't prefer non-voting secondaries over voting secondaries, so with secondary Read Preference you can only ensure that all read operations are performed on your 4 secondary nodes. That should be perfectly fine though, as if you limited read operations only for non-voting replicas, those two voting secondaries would not perform either reads or writes (unless one of them gets elected as primary).
